# install an older version of xcode on mac lion 10.7

Tags: macos, mac, xcode

I want to install xcode on vmware image mac os x lion 10.7 ..
I went to app store but it won't let me download because it's the latest version which not compatible with lion 10.7 ..
I don't have an developer account .. 
So, is there any way to install an old xcode ?

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to login to [Downloads for Apple Developers](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/) with your Apple ID. From there, search for "Xcode 4." You should see "Xcode 4.6.3" at the top of the list. It includes the iOS 6.1 SDK and OS X 10.8 SDK. This is the last version of Xcode supported by OS X Lion (10.7.x) and was released on June 13, 2013.

Answer (score 3):

You can get older versions of Xcode in the [Developer Center Downloads](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode) section you can go through the pages of Xcode related downloads to find the one you're looking for. You may need to log in to access this page.

Comment: Thx bro for helping ..
I did what you said and now i can browse all versions of xcode ..
I have Mac OS X Lion 10.7 .. 
What version of xcode should i download .. ???

Comment: I think version 4.6.3 is the latest compatible with Lion.

Comment: as i see in the dev page .. 4.3.3 is the latest ver of xcode for Mac OS X Lion 10.7

Comment: 4.6.3 (from June 13, 2013) is the latest I found working on Lion 10.7.5